# copy result from api response to clipboard safari

Tags: javascript, reactjs, safari

It seems safari only allows an item to be copied to clipboard after a user interaction, is it possible to have a api request's results copied to a clipboard?

In my case a user clicks to copy, a api endpoint is hit, we get the results, then try to copy to clipboard. But I keep getting the error:

> Unhandled Promise Rejection: NotAllowedError: The request is not
> allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context,
> possibly because the user denied permission.

This is what the code looks like:

```
if (navigator.clipboard) {
    await navigator.clipboard.writeText(text);
    }
```

Ive tried resolving the promise directly inside the writeText method as well but yet I still get the same error.

Please let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: It shouldn't matter where the source is - API or not. Try setting just "hello world" and copy it to the clipboard

Comment: It is not possible, as the doc says https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/write . Need a transient activation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/User_activation

Comment: Provide more context around the code. It may be that the snippet you've shown is outside the click event handler because it was used as a callback to a promise. Async/await would let you keep the copy command in the click handler and satisfy the user interaction requirement.